# Does there exist a generalization of distributions?

Tags: banach-spaces, distribution-theory

We know that distributions are generalizations of mappings from $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $\mathbb{C}$. As an analog, is there a generalizations of mappings $\mathbb{R}^n$ into $X$ where $X$ is assumed to be a Banach space. Moreover, does a similar generalized Fourier transform exist? In the analog sense of mapping tempered distributions onto tempered distributions.

Comment: I'd challenge you to write down the precise definition of a distribution (in the sense of generalizing maps $\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{C}$) and then see what happens when you replace $\mathbb{C}$ with a general Banach space. Does the definition still make sense? If so, what might it be useful for? If not, what about the definition would need to change to make sense?

Comment: @Neal In terms of usefulness, it should at least be useful in quantum mechanics, in the sense, that "operators" are usually a mapping from $\mathbb{R^n}$ or $\mathbb{Z}^n$ into the space of densely defined or bounded operators on a Hilbert space. It is common to take the Fourier transform of such "operators", but whether that's well-defined is not so clear to me.

Comment: Have a look at [these notes](https://www.math.uzh.ch/amann/files/distributions.ps) by Herbert Amann: perhaps you'll find something which suits your purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and it is very useful for PDE. A lot of evolution problems can be written under the form
$$u^\prime(t) = Au(t)$$
where $u$ is a distribution on $\mathbb R$ with values in a Banach or Hilbert space  $E$ (typically a Sobolev space).

For more details, you can check for instance the chapter 39 "Functions and Distributions Valued in Banach Spaces" of *Trèves, François. Basic linear partial differential equations. Vol. 62. Academic press, 1975*.